# Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically - Razor Language

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to use Parallel.ForEach combine with lambda expression program by RAZOR language.

The Code:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach(ViewBag.FontsProps.fonts, font =>
{
   //Do something

});
```

The error:

> Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically
>   dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or
>   expression

Any Idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried casting ViewBag.FontsProps.fonts to type you are expecting?

Comment: Do you have this error if you replace first parameter passed to ForEach with something like: new string[] { "one", "two"}?